# Docker Compose not respecting password variable and not creating role

Tags: postgresql, docker

Current config:

```
version: '3.5'

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.24
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=user
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password2
     - POSTGRES_DB=dummy
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
```

Running a `docker-compose up` and not getting the role `user` created for whatever reason.

It does create the database:

```
db_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1  | 
db_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1  | 
db_1  | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-08 06:20:22 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server started
db_1  | CREATE DATABASE
```

Yet I'm able to access the database **without** needing a password

```
# psql -U user dummy
psql (9.6.24)
Type "help" for help.

dummy=#
```

Anyone know why this is the case?

This container was made all from scratch so I don't know what's missing here.

Comment: Where are you running the `psql`?

Comment: @Bergi in the container

Comment: In that case, you're automatically trusted because you connect over a unix domain socket

Comment: @Bergi sorry for the stupid question, but I've done the same docker-compose file for a mysql container and it won't allow me in the database _without_ a password input. Is there some file that I'm overlooking?

Comment: That's [just the default configuration of postgres](https://superuser.com/a/1692803/175275) (which you can change for your container if you don't like it). mysql would have a different default configuration, and I don't even know if it supports unix sockets or "trust" authorisation.

Comment: @Bergi thank you! I will take a look. Appreciate it.